# iOS Quick Action Share with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, 3dtouch

Im struggling with iOS 3d touch / quick actions. I'm trying to implement a Quick Action Share button similar to Hangouts App using UIActivityViewController.

Following iOS dev guildes I have almost managed to achieve the goal but my application is starting with the splash & home screen right after performing the 3d touch click while the Hangouts app presents the UIActivityViewController without showing any viewcontroller beneath it.

```
- (void)handleShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)item {
   NSString *string = @"Share String";
   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some URL"];

   UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[string, URL] applicationActivities:nil];
   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Does anyone know how to launch those quick actions without launching the whole app?

Comment: I think that this Share feature might be added for each and every app downloaded from app store and it is independed of the Quick Actions implementation. Can anyone confirm to this statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shortcut item is added for each and every app downloaded from the App Store (at least on my device running iOS 10). There's no need for you to implement anything!

Note that TestFlight builds will have a "Send Feedback" shortcut option instead of "Share ___"

Comment: Is the share shortcut item displayed only on release builds ? because I can't see it on my debug build, and is there a way to remove it ?

Comment: it's not on debug builds. I haven't found a way to remove it, yet @Mosbah

Comment: Share is shown on release, and "Send Beta Feedback" is shown on Test Flight builds. **The shortcut is added even if app has 4 shortcuts of their own**, no need to add manually.

Comment: Is there any way to remove "Send Beta Feedback" from shortcut menu in case of TestFlight builds ?